# Best way to create select all checkboxes on table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm newbie on VueJS and I'm create a data table component, so far I have created two components: `ui-datatable` and `ui-checkbox`, that allows me check all rows from table. Is working perfectly, but I think there must be some smarter way to do it. Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nicolasluishuber/kh2of0yq/11/), I accept suggestions, I feel that I did more laps in my code.

Comment: Didn't see first that this was Vue related question and I was going to suggest just having each checkbox with same class and use class selector to select all of them them. Not sure how to apply it in Vue though :/

Answer (score 1):

Your checkbox component seems to make things more complicated rather than simpler. I just put in regular checkbox inputs:

```
        <input type="checkbox" v-model="selectAll" />
```

and

```
        <input type="checkbox" v-model="selected" :value="row.id" />
```

Then I modified `selectAll`'s setter to use `value` instead of `value.checked` and rephrased the formula (no impact on performance - I think your technique is fine):

```
  set: function (value) {
    this.selected = value ? this.rows.map((row) => row.id.toString()) : [];
  }
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kh2of0yq/13/)